# Screen capture program on Mac OS X Lion, preferable portable on other OS

Tags: c#, java, .net, c++, screen-capture

I need to develop a screen capture program that runs on Mac OS X Lion. I tried to make a screenshot using `mono` and `GTK#`, but the screenshot is black

```
Gdk.Window window = Gdk.Global.DefaultRootWindow;
if (window!=null)
{           
    Gdk.Pixbuf pixBuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(Gdk.Colorspace.Rgb, false, 8, 
                                       window.Screen.Width, window.Screen.Height);          
    pixBuf.GetFromDrawable(window, Gdk.Colormap.System, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                           window.Screen.Width, window.Screen.Height);          
    pixBuf.ScaleSimple(400, 300, Gdk.InterpType.Bilinear);
    pixBuf.Save("screenshot0.jpeg", "jpeg");
}
```

Can you point me in right direction. Preferably using `mono`, but if will be `java`, `c++` or `objective c` is also good.
Thank in advance.

Comment: I doubt the Mac OS port of Gtk portably gives you low-level access to the platform windowing system. The GDK documentation mentions GDK_ROOT_WINDOW() as an backend-specific function.

Comment: The `DefaultRootWindow` concept comes from X Windows. I'd be surprised if it translated properly to OS X.

Comment: I don't know, i tried using DefaultRootWindow, see in question, but it makes black screens.

Comment: @croisharp Yes, what I meant is that DefaultRootWindow probably only works on Linux. (Or rather, under X11.) It's entirely possible the OS X port of GDK gives you a dummy implementation that doesn't return useful data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Java, see [Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).  Note though, that `Robot` commonly also produces a black screen image for apps. that take direct control of the screen area (e.g. many games).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be using a platform-specific API to do the actual image capture, while the rest of your app remains portable. For OS X, Apple actually provides [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) on how to do this, and your code will probably work under X11.